# How to create an accelerator for CTRL+? in code

Tags: c, winapi

I want to create an accelerator for the combination `CTRL+?` using `CreateAcceleratorTable()`. How do I have to fill in the `ACCEL` structure? I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
a.fVirt = FCONTROL;
a.key = '?';
a.cmd = IDM_HELP;
```

I cannot use `FVIRTKEY` because there doesn't seem to be a virtual key code for the `?` key. There is `VK_OEM_2` but [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) it maps to the `?` key only on US keyboards. I need to be compatible with various European keyboards as well.

So how am I supposed to install an accelerator for `CTRL+?` then? Note that I don't want to use resources, but `CreateAcceleratorTable()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Using Keyboard Accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/using-keyboard-accelerators) documentation:

> You define an accelerator's keystroke by **specifying an ASCII character code or a virtual-key code** in the `key` member of the `ACCEL` structure. If you specify a virtual-key code, you must first include the `FVIRTKEY` flag in the `fVirt` member; otherwise, the system interprets the code as an ASCII character code. You can include the `FCONTROL`, `FALT`, or `FSHIFT` flag, or all three, to combine the CTRL, ALT, or SHIFT key with the keystroke.

`?` is an ASCII character, so `a.key = '?';` works just fine if you do not enable the `FVIRTKEY` flag.

However, `?` requires the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key in order to type it.  In general, you cannot create a <kbd>CTRL+[Char]</kbd> accelerator for any ASCII character that requires <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to type it, which includes **uppercase** letters and the symbols `~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?`.

In this case, to create an accelerator for the ASCII `?` character, you can:

- create <kbd>SHIFT+?</kbd>, using either an ASCII code or a virtual key code, both work fine.
- create <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+?</kbd>, using a virtual key code only. If you try using the ASCII code for `?` (or any shiftable ASCII character), when both `FCONTROL` and `FSHIFT` are enabled, oddly only <kbd>SHIFT+[Char]</kbd> will trigger the `WM_COMMAND` message!  But, with a virtual key code, <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+[Char]</kbd> works fine.

To get the virtual key code for an ASCII character, you can use [`VkKeyScan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanw) or [`VkKeyScanEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexw):

> Translates a character to the corresponding virtual-key code and shift state.

Translate the ASCII character into a virtual key code and shift bits, and then translate the shift bits into `ACCEL` flags.  For example:

```
TCHAR ch = ...; // whichever ASCII character you want

SHORT res = VkKeyScan(ch);
WORD vk = LOBYTE(res);
WORD shift = HIBYTE(res);

a.fVirt = FVIRTKEY;
a.key = vk;
a.cmd = ...;

if (shift & 1) a.fVirt |= FSHIFT;
if (shift & 2) a.fVirt |= FCONTROL;
if (shift & 4) a.fVirt |= FALT;

// add on whichever additional control keys you need
...
```

However, if you really want an accelerator for <kbd>CTRL+[Char]</kbd>, such as <kbd>CTRL+?</kbd>, you will have to ue the virtual key code for the key that includes the character and omit the `SHIFT` state, eg:

```
TCHAR ch = TEXT('?'); // or whatever

a.fVirt = FVIRTKEY | FCONTROL;
a.key = LOBYTE(VkKeyScan(ch));
a.cmd = ...;
```

Then <kbd>CTRL+[Char]</kbd> will work.

Comment: The documentation is a little vague. You cannot use `FCONTROL` (or `FSHIFT`) with ASCII characters. The asker wants `Ctrl+?`, therefore use the second method (the user will have to press `Ctrl+Shift+?`)

Comment: "*You cannot use `FCONTROL` (or `FSHIFT`) with ASCII characters*" - yes, you can.  I tried it, it works fine **in general**, with some exceptions.  However, you just can't make an accelerator for `CTRL+[char]` for ASCII characters that require `SHIFT` to type them, like `?`, upper-case letters, etc. I updated my answer.

Comment: I mean `ACCEL a = { FCONTROL, 'x', IDM_HELP};` doesn't work, where `x` is any ASCII character (it works with `FALT` or zero). But `ACCEL a = { FCONTROL|FVIRTKEY, LOBYTE(VkKeyScan('?')), IDM_HELP};` will respond to `Ctrl+?`

Comment: I could have sworn `ACCEL a = { FCONTROL, 'x', IDM_HELP};` worked, I thought I tested it successfully before posting my last comment. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Note that the second code snippet in your answer won't work on keyboards where `?` needs the shift key (e.g. a German keyboard). In that case I have to examine the `HIBYTE` value returned by `VkKeyScan()` and set `FSHIFT` if needed, just as you described in your first code snippet.

Comment: @Andreas US keyboards require SHIFT to *type* `?`. But you don't need the SHIFT to get the virtual key code of the physical key that `?` resides on, and that is all you really need. That is the goal of the second code example.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying '/'?

Keyboard accelerators do not take characters, like the ? char.
You can also use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa to map a character to a virtual key.